# Selenium GeckoDriver is slow to launch Firefox Browser

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have recently been trying to get a Selenium environment up and running again. Everything works as it should with scripts executing as they should, using different web drivers etc etc.

However, the initial launch of each driver takes anywhere between 2-5 min to launch. This makes it a pain to develop and troubleshoot my scripts.

I use Python 3.6 with PyCharm and Selenium installed with pip. The same issue is present with Python 2.7.

Things I have tried so far (without success):

- Reinstalled Python
- Reinstalled Selenium
- Run the script through PyCharm and via a terminal
- Replaced the web drivers with earlier and later versions.
- Disabled proxy and javascript for the web drivers

Here is what I am running. This simple script takes up to 5min to run, but works correctly and returns no warnings or errors.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
print(time.localtime())
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
print(time.localtime())
```

EDIT:
A single run of the code above yields the following geckodriver.log

```
1528112695159   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1528112695168   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:3148
1528112747876   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\victorsk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.ULuflXGoq9rE"
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1528112791808   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 3158
1528112792599   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
[Parent 36664, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Parent 36664, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 22672, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 22672, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/sr[Parent 36664, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 25068, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 25068, C*** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for id: telemetry_modules_ping
```

Comment: Update the question with the _GeckoDriver_ console logs

Answer (score 1):

These error messages...

```
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
```

...implies that there were several attempts to read the existing  `VR Path Registry from C:\Users\victorsk\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath`.

Your main issue is the presence of **os chores** within your system.

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *unknown* to us.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is **v0.19.1**.
- Your *Firefox* version is *unknown* to us.

### Solution

To speed up the operation follow the steps:

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Ensure *GeckoDriver* binary is present in the specified location.
- Ensure *GeckoDriver* is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v60.0.1*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

> **Note**: Do not *disable* **JavaScript**. Disabling **JavaScript** might lead to a incomplete loading of the webpage as all the web designers/developers believes *JavaScript* is available in every browser and all the recent browser features and effects are implemented using *JavaScript*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both my Selenium and Firefox already were updated to latest versions. Followed all your other suggestions. But I still have the exact same problem. Your suggestions cleared the pipe errors in the log but otherwise, it is the same.

Comment: @Verzus Can you update the question with your _current environment details (including GeckoDriver base version)_, _current code block_ and **_trace level logs_** for further analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but same problem, using C#.

The solution is deleting the contents of the "storage" folder inside the profile before launching selenium.

I needed the cookies stored on the profile, so cleaning from the browser is not an option.

C# code to do it programmatically, convert it to your specific language:

```
private void buttonCleanProfCacheRespectCookies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    string firefoxProfilesPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles");

    // Optional, if you want to see the folder by yourself
    //Process.Start("explorer.exe", firefoxProfilesPath);


    // The folder name is something cryptic like g7ufgsz3w72n.MySeleniumProfile, so its better to look for it using a partial match
    const string PARTIAL_PROFILE_NAME = "Selenium";

    deleteStorageContents(firefoxProfilesPath, PARTIAL_PROFILE_NAME);
}

static void deleteStorageContents(string firefoxProfilesPath, string partialProfileName)
{
    try
    {
        // Search for a folder with the partial name inside the specified path
        string[] matchingProfiles = Directory.GetDirectories(firefoxProfilesPath, "*" + partialProfileName + "*");

        foreach (string profile in matchingProfiles)
        {
            string storagePath = Path.Combine(profile, "storage");

            // Check if the "storage" folder exists before attempting to delete its contents
            if (Directory.Exists(storagePath))
            {
                // Delete all files within the "storage" folder
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(storagePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                }

                // Delete all subdirectories within the "storage" folder
                foreach (string subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(storagePath))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(subDirectory, true);
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Contents of 'storage' folder in profile '{profile}' deleted.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"'storage' folder not found in profile '{profile}'.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```